# Angular 5 - HTTPClient + Observable + Displaying Data

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am trying to access data from an WP Rest API that I have created that returns [sample data](https://b.leia.uicentric.net/wp-json/wp/v2/documents).

I am trying to then access the array of data either via an iterator or just by something like `data[0]`.

I'm very new to Angular, and particularly to Angular 5.

I have a model:

```
export class Tool {
  id: string;
  acf: object;

  constructor(id: string, acf: object) {
    this.id = id;
    this.acf = acf;
  }
}
```

A service that hits the API:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    import { Tool } from 'app/models/tool';
    import { environment } from 'environments/environment';

    @Injectable()
    export class ToolsService {
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

      getAll(): Observable<Tool[]> {
        return this.http.get(<myUrl>)
      }
    }
```

And then a component:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    import { Tool } from 'app/models/tool';
    import { ToolsService } from 'app/services/tools.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-tools-documentation',
      templateUrl: './tools-documentation.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./tools-documentation.component.scss'],
      providers: [ToolsService]
    })
    export class ToolsDocumentationComponent implements OnInit {
      tools$: Observable<Tool[]>;

      constructor(private toolsService: ToolsService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.tools$ = this.toolsService.getAll()
      }
    }
```

I'm able to display the $tools on the page via something like:
`<pre>{{tools$ | async | json}}</pre>`

But if I try to iterate over it (or access individual elements), I get errors around the types not matching or the Observable not actually being an array. How do I properly format this to access this data and iterate over it in the view? Every answer I find seems to use the old Angular 4 way of doing things and doesn't use HTTPClient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem does not lie in whether you use `Http` or `HttpClient`.

To unwrap observables and loop through it:`<div *ngFor="let tool of tools$ | async"> {{tool.id}}</div>`

Comment: And further it should be possible to do something like this:
<ng-container *ngIf="tools$ | async as tools">
<div *ngFor="let tool of tools"> {{tool.id}}</div>
<span>{{tools.length}}</span>
</ng-container>

Comment: Thanks, I was using the AsyncPipe incorrectly and your two answers combined gave me exactly what I needed.